# Android duration of notification on home screen

Tags: android, notifications

I want to show notification on home screen. This is my code:

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
.setContentTitle("Connection request")
.setContentText("content text")
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_done)
.setContentIntent(pi)
.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
   mBuilder.setVibrate(new long [0]);

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mNotificationManager.notify(1300, mBuilder.build());
```

On this step all works fine, BUT notification disappears after 5 second.

Is it possible to create notification like when we receive incoming call? Or something else duration? I mean on home screen.

I know that it is possible, because it works in apps like WhatsApp.

I try to set long vibration and long sound, but notification disappears from home screen after 5 second and sound and vibration continue to play.

Thank You!

**EDIT**

```
public class WaitConnectionService extends Service {

public final static int START_CONNECTION = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

private Looper mServiceLooper;
private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
    public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
        super(looper);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {

        System.out.println("HANDLE MESSAGE");
        if (msg.what == START_CONNECTION) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

//                        new TCPServer().run();

                    Intent i = new Intent(WaitConnectionService.this, ListActivity.class);

                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                            i, 0);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
                    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                            (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

                    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setContentTitle("Connection request")
                            .setContentText("content text")
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_done)
                            .setContentIntent(pi)
                            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                            .setUsesChronometer(true)
                            .addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_done,
                                    "ok", pIntent).build());

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21)
                        mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[0]);

                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                    mNotificationManager.notify(1300, mBuilder.build());

                }
            }).start();

        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    System.out.println("ON CREATE");
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("My handler thread", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {

    System.out.println("ON START COMMAND");
    Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
    msg.what = START_CONNECTION;
    msg.arg1 = startId;
    mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    System.out.println("Service onDestroy(");
}
}
```

And in Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, WaitConnectionService.class);
    intent1.putExtra("what", 1);

    startService(intent1);
}
```

When I run this code it starts main activity, and shows notification only 5 sec.

**FIND SOLUTION FROM THIS EXAMPLE**

[https://github.com/googlesamples/android-LNotifications](http://googlesamples_android-LNotifications)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `START_NOT_STICKY` in `onStartCommand()` of the service. This means your service will stop automatically. Instead use `START_STICKY`.

Comment: Are You trying this. For me it does not work. My android version is 6.0.1, and I try to use NotificationCompat and Notification but... only 5 sec.

Comment: Try testing it on a lower version instead. There may be power saver mode enabled on that device. Try changing the settings.

Comment: I check power safe mode - disabled. I think it's not a power safe mode problem because WhatsApp notification works fine (more than 5 seconds on home screen).

Comment: Where are you calling this code from? Are you cancelling the notification somewhere?

Comment: I am calling it from service handleMessage function: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService In handleMessage  I create new Thread and call it from this thread. And I does not cancelling it anywhere.

Comment: Don't call it. Can you post the code where you're starting this notification from?

Comment: return START_STICKY; does not resolve problem, only 5 sec.

Comment: Then I guess the problem resides somewhere else. Why do you need the handler to to start the notification?

Comment: Ok, without handler it does not work too. I put notification code in onStartCommand and notifications shows only 5 sec! I do not understand how to create notification that shows more than 5 sec.

Comment: Try implementing them from [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Notifications) tutorial.